# How to properly conditionally transclude a custom component without it being initialized using angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template

I have a component (named card) that transcludes another component (named graph) in another component (named edit), but i don't want the **component B** to initialize itself.
So i tried to add a condition to the `ng-content` tag but the **component B** has still initialize itself.

Template **component edit**:

```
<component-card>
    <component-graph></component-graph>
</component-card>
```

Template **component card**:

```
<mat-card>
   ...
   <mat-card-content *ngIf="open">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <!-- doesn't work too<ng-content *ngIf="open"></ng-content> -->
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**Component graph**'s typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init'); // this is called
    // i don't want this component to load the data before he's displayed
    this.loadData();
}
```

Here `open` is always false but the **component graph** is still calling it's `ngOnInit` method

so i've tried to created an output in the **component card** that emit the `open` value when it changes

and in the **component edit** i've added a new variable that takes the open state each time it changes:

```
<component-card (openStateChange)="displayGraph = $event>
    <component-graph *ngIf="displayGraph"></component-graph>
</component-card>
```

It's working but i don't know if there is another way to do this properly maybe using the `ng-content` for exemple, if someone have an idea because i don't found any articles on it... maybe it's the proper way because the **component graph** relates to the **component edit** but i prefer ask.

Another thing is that the component isn't displayed, so visualy it's good but the `ngOnInit` is called, and the problem is that i don't want my data to be loaded before the component is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something.. but.. why can't we just put the `ngIf` directive on both `mat-card` and `ng-content`? (in the template of component A)

This way the entire content element will not be initialized, preventing component B to load

```
<mat-card>
...
   <mat-card-content *ngIf="open">
      <ng-content *ngIf="open"></ng-content>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Yes i've tried it but i don't know why the `ngOnInit` of the component B is still called (and it's the only place he's used in my app), i've forced open to be false everytime and it still calls the `ngOnInit` method

Comment: even when using `<ng-content *ngIf="open">`? this is truly strange.. are you sure about your findings?

Comment: Yes, i don't know why, i've edited the components names, maybe it will be more easier to understand

Comment: The thing that works using this method is that the component isn't displayed but the problem is that it's build once (so in my case its loading ma datas and i don't want it)